# Q: Prove that if $f(a)g(b) = f(b)g(a),$ then there exists $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x)/f(x)=g'(x)/g(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I have to prove the following statement holds:

> Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. Let $f,g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(x)\ne0$, $g(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. If $f(a)g(b)=f(b)g(a)$, then there exists some $x_{0}\in(a,b)$ such that $\frac{f'(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}=\frac{g'(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})}$.

I have thought about using both the intermediate value theorem and the mean value theorem, since the functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous and differentiable. For example, we have by the mean value theorem that $\exists x_{0}\in(a,b)$ such that

$$
f(b)-f(a)=f'(x_{0})(b-a)
$$

and

$$
g(b)-g(a)=g'(x_{0})(b-a)
$$

whereby

$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(x_{0})}{g'(x_{0})}
$$

I'm not entirely sure how to use the hypothesis that $f(a)g(b)=f(b)g(a)$ from here. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Edit: This is the proof I have come up with:

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(x)\ne 0$, $g(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Suppose $f(a)g(b)=f(b)g(a)$. Then $\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}=\frac{g(a)}{g(b)}$. Let $p(x)=\ln(|f(x)|)$ and $q(x)=\ln(|g(x)|)$, then

> $$
> p'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \text{ for all } x\in(a,b)
> $$

> while

> $$
> q'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \text{ for all } x\in(a,b)
> $$

> Furthermore, given some $x_{0}\in(a,b)$, according to the mean value theorem we obtain

> $$
> p(b)-p(a)=p'(x_{0})(b-a)\Longrightarrow \ln(\left|\frac{f(b)}{f(a)}\right|)=\frac{f'(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}(b-a)
> $$
> similarly, if $x_{0}\in(a,b)$ then

> $$
> q(b)-q(a)=q'(x_{0})(b-a)\Longrightarrow \ln(\left|\frac{g(b)}{g(a)}\right|)=\frac{g'(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})}(b-a)
> $$

> By hypothesis, we have

> $$
> \ln(\left|\frac{g(b)}{g(a)}\right|)=\ln(\left|\frac{f(b)}{f(a)}\right|)
> $$
> and thus

> $$
> \frac{f'(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}(b-a)=\frac{g'(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})}(b-a)\Longrightarrow
> \frac{f'(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}=\frac{g'(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})}
> $$

From the comments below there is an issue with choosing $x_{0}\in(a,b)$ for both functions using the mean-value theorem. This is the only part of the proof I am struggling with now.

Comment: Hint: rewrite $f(a)g(b) = f(b)g(a)$ as $f(a)/g(a) = f(b)/g(b)$.

Comment: Note: your approach has a flaw. The mean value theorem tells you that there exists $x_0 \in (a,b)$ such that $f(b) - f(a) = f'(x_0)(b-a)$ and that there exists $x_1 \in (a,b)$ such that $g(b) - g(a) = g'(x_1)(b-a)$, but there is no guarantee that $x_0 = x_1$!

Comment: Good point. I'll have to make note of that. If I let $p(x)=ln(|f(x)|)$ and $q(x)=ln(|g(x)|)$ as has been suggested below then I can avoid that, I think.

Comment: What will you do differently to avoid this issue?

Comment: Wouldn't continuity on $[a,b]$ and differentiability on $(a,b)$ be enough to guarantee that you could come up with $x_{0},x_{1}\in(a,b)$ such that $x_{0}=x_{1}$?

Comment: No, it certainly is not enough. For example, consider $\sin$ and $\cos$ on $[0,2\pi]$. We have $\sin(2\pi) - \sin(0) = \cos(2\pi) - \cos(0) = 0$. Thus, there exist $x_0, x_1 \in (0,2\pi)$ such that $2\pi \sin'(x_0) = 0 = 2\pi \cos'(x_1)$; equivalently $\sin'(x_0) = \cos'(x_1) = 0$. But $\sin' = \cos$ and $\cos' = -\sin$, and these have no common zeros, therefore there is no way to choose $x_0$ and $x_1$ to be the same point.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I am just having a hard time seeing why this is so important. Certainly I can pick $x_{0}\in(a,b)$ such that the derivative exists, and the mean value theorem guarantees that $f'(x_{0}) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and it also guarantees that $g'(x_{0}) = \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$. The mean value theorem says nothing, however, about guaranteeing that the two functions $f,g$ have derivatives that are identical at that point. Furthermore, this statement is suggesting that they're only identical up to some constants $f(x_{0})$ and $g(x_{0})$. Enlighten me.

Comment: Notice that you are applying the mean value theorem two times here. Each time, the mean value theorem gives you some point in the interval $(a,b)$ where the derivative of the function you applied it to equals the average rate of change across the interval, but the two applications of the mean value theorem to these two different functions are not guaranteed to give you the same point! My example showed that indeed it may be impossible for the two points to be the same, so this is really a very important issue. This has nothing to do with the values of the derivatives being equal/unequal.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now. I had to process what is happening a little more. I will think about this a little more before I attempt to process the remainder of my proof. Thanks!

Comment: @MrStormy83 Your stated proof is good. However, consider using a new function $r(x) = p(x)-q(x)$. You get $r(a) = r(b)$ so, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists an $x_0 \in (a, b)$ where $r'(x_0) = 0$. Since $r'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$, the required result follows. I'm sorry if my hint perhaps indicated using just your $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ separately, but as you state in your question update, you need to have just one $x_0$, so this can be done by combining the $2$ functions appropriately into $1$ function, with this case involving subtracting one function from the other.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification on your hint. I think that nicely eliminates the problem indicated throughout these comments regarding the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You have the right idea, but use $\ln(|f(x)|)$ and $\ln(|g(x)|)$ instead since, for example, by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), we have

$$\frac{d(\ln(|f(x)|)}{dx} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$